# jQuery validate $.validator.addClassRules() unsupported in IE7?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, internet-explorer-7

I'm having some issues with the following script in IE7:

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
   isemail: {
       email: true
   },
    required: {
        required: true
    }   
});
```

This works perfectly in IE8 and other browsers however I get the following error in IE7:

```
Line: 158
Char: 3
Error: Expected ':'
```

In my code, this line is:

```
isemail: {
```

There is no mention of a lack of support for this function on the jQuery validate plugin site (http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) so is there something i'm missing here?

The version of jQuery I am using is `jQuery v1.10.2`. The version of jQuery validate I am using is 1.11.1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: jQuery Validate 1.11.1 has only been tested up through jQuery 1.9.

Comment: Are you testing in a ***real*** copy of IE 7?

Comment: Yes. I'm testing on a version of IE7 installed on a virtual machine.

Comment: Perfect.  Try jQuery v1.9 then.  Otherwise, you may have found a bug. However, I don't know how interested the developer would be in fixing something for such an old browser.

Comment: Tried this with v1.9 and that makes no difference.

Comment: Usage of the `.addClassRules()` method does not make sense in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"Any help would be greatly appreciated."*

Your code:

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
    isemail: {
        email: true
    },
    required: {
        required: true
    }   
});
```

The way you've written it, you want to use `class="isemail"` and `class="required"` within your `input` element markup.

```
<input class="isemail" type="text" ...
<input class="required" type="text" ...
```

**HOWEVER**, by default, you can already place the standard rules in the `class` attribute ***without*** the `.addClassRules()` method.

```
<input class="email" type="text" ...
<input class="required" type="text" ...
<input class="email required" type="text" ...
```

The `.addClassRules()` method is intended for creating *compound* rules from sets of standard rules and assigning the compound rule to a new `class` name.

[From the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/):

> **Description**: Add a *compound* class method – useful to refactor common combinations of rules into a single `class`.

**Stock examples from documentation**

For multiple `class` names:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    myClass: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    },
    myClass2: {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 5
    }
});
```

or for a single `class` name:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('myClass', {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    }
});
```

Since you haven't shown us any compound rules, you wouldn't need this method at all.  By default, the rule's name will work as the `class` name.  (*there are exceptions: only rules that can be declared with a boolean value can be declared through the `class`.*)

```
<input class="required" type="text" ...
<input class="email" type="text" ...
```

You could even simulate a compound rule (again, this is **without** the `.addClassMethod()`).

```
<input class="required email" type="text" ...
```

**Quote OP**:

> *"... [is] `.addClassRules()` unsupported in IE7? .... There is no mention of a lack of support for this function on the jquery validate plugin site, so is there something i'm missing here?"*

You may have found a bug specific to IE7, however since [usage of IE7 is practically zero](http://theie7countdown.com/), I don't think I'd expect a fix or even worry about it too much.

However, by taking my simple suggestions above, you negate the need for the `.addClassRules()` method and will continue to support IE7.

---

**EDIT**:

If you cannot change the HTML markup, you can add to the `class`'s [using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/).  This will assign `.email` to every element that already contains `.isemail`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.isemail').addClass('email');  // put this at the top

});
```

Comment: It is required in this case though as I cannot modify the base HTML. Typically we use ExtJS for validation and the class we use for Email is isemail. Many government bodies and departments still support IE7 so we have to provide support for this browser. Ultimately a simple solution to this is just using the jQuery .addClass method to assign a class of email to anything with the class of ieemail.

Comment: @jezzpin, using jQuery, you could assign the `email` class to every element with the `isemail` class.

Comment: `$('.isemail').addClass('email')`

Comment: Lol.  I see now I just repeated what you already said.   Oh well, hopefully that solved it for you.